# how i can send a receive a data from second time using the same open socket in mule java?

Tags: java, sockets, mule, mule-component

Hi to everyone on this Forum, on this ocassion I need a help from the community because I don't understand how to keep open the socket to send and receive data from a device. For instance when I send a first command to receive an answer, successfully I receive an answer, but after this first send/receive when I'm trying to send back a second command I have no response and in ocassions throws an error.

This is the class that I used in mule 3.5 CE java 1.7

```
public class TCPMuleOutBasic extends TcpMessageReceiver {


     public TCPMuleOutBasic(Connector connector, FlowConstruct flowConstruct,
             InboundEndpoint endpoint) throws CreateException {
         super(connector, flowConstruct, endpoint);
     }

     protected Work createWork(Socket socket) throws IOException {
         return new MyTcpWorker(socket, this);
     }


     protected class MyTcpWorker extends TcpMessageReceiver.TcpWorker {

         public MyTcpWorker(Socket socket, AbstractMessageReceiver receiver)
                 throws IOException {
             super(socket, receiver);
             // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         }

         @Override
         protected Object getNextMessage(Object resource) throws Exception {
             ArrayList<String> testarr2 = new ArrayList<>();
             BufferedReader entrada;
             //Socket clientSocket = null;
             try{
                 ArrayList<String> testarr = new ArrayList<>();

                 //this.socket.
                 //clientSocket = this.socket;

                 //OPEN IN BUFFER, DE ENTRADA
                 entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
                 //OPEN OUT BUFFER DE SALIDA ENVIA COMANDO 
                 PrintStream pingStream = new PrintStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());

                 //PrintStream pingStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                 System.out.println("STATUS SOCKET VAL 1.2: "+this.socket.isClosed()+" CON "+isConnected());
                 testarr = this.enviarComando("#SER",1,this.socket,entrada,pingStream);
                 System.out.println("ARRAY VALOR 1: " + testarr.get(0));

                 //OPEN A SECOND TIME, THIS IS MY PROBLEM DONT WORK

                 //ABRO BUFFER DE ENTRADA
                 entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
                 //ABRO BUFFER DE SALIDA ENVIA COMANDO 
                 pingStream = new PrintStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());


                 System.out.println("STATUS SOCKET VAL 2: "+this.socket.isClosed()+" CON "+isConnected());
                 testarr2 = this.enviarComando("#NLO",2,this.socket,entrada,pingStream);
                 /*System.out.println("ARREGLO VALOR 2: " + testarr2.get(0));*/

                 dataIn.close();
                 return testarr;
             }catch(IOException e)
             {
                 System.out.println("ERROR ARREGLO:"+e.getMessage());
                 return null;
             }

         }//FIN NEXTMESSANGE

         //METODO PARA HACER PETICION
         //FUNCTION TO SEND A RECIVE DATA
         protected ArrayList<String> enviarComando (String comando,int req,Socket openSocket,BufferedReader entrada,PrintStream pingStream) throws Exception {
             boolean InitConnection = false;
             String lineaComando;
             String mensajeServidor;
             Socket clientSocket = null;
             ArrayList<String> retorno = new ArrayList<String>();

             try{

                 if (InitConnection == false) {
                     lineaComando = comando;
                     System.out.println("Mandando Comandos:"+lineaComando);
                     clientSocket = openSocket;
                     String direccion = clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                     System.out.println("Direccion:"+direccion);
                     System.out.println("Cliente en línea ="+req);




                     System.out.println("Comando enviado:" + lineaComando);
                     lineaComando = lineaComando + CRC.getCrc16Ccitt(lineaComando) + "\r";
                     pingStream.print(lineaComando);

                     //entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                     //entrada.ready();
                     System.out.println("STATUS FLUJO DE ENTRADA ="+req+entrada.ready());


                     int contador = 0;
                     System.out.println("ENTRADA: "+entrada.toString());
                     while((mensajeServidor = entrada.readLine()) != null) //Mientras haya mensajes desde el cliente
                     {    
                         contador++;
                         //Se muestra por pantalla el mensaje recibido
                         retorno.add(mensajeServidor); 
                         System.out.println("mensaje dispositivo "+contador+ ": "+ mensajeServidor);
                     }
                     /*
                     lineaComando = "#NLO";
                     System.out.println("Mandando 2do Comandos:"+lineaComando);
                     lineaComando = lineaComando + CRC.getCrc16Ccitt(lineaComando) + "\r";
                     pingStream.print(lineaComando);
                     while((mensajeServidor = entrada.readLine()) != null) //Mientras haya mensajes desde el cliente
                     {    
                         contador++;
                         //Se muestra por pantalla el mensaje recibido
                         retorno.add(mensajeServidor); 
                         System.out.println("mensaje dispositivo Segundo"+contador+ ": "+ mensajeServidor);
                     }*/


                     InitConnection = true;
                 }

                 //dataIn.close();
                 InitConnection = false;
                 logger.debug("Socket timeout");
                 System.out.println("CIERRO SOCKET");
                 return retorno;
             }catch (SocketException e )
             {
                 System.out.println("ERROR F:"+e.getMessage()+" "+comando+" Request: "+req);
                 return null;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

THE CONNECTOR AND FLOW.

```
    <tcp:connector name="TCP" doc:name="TCP connector"
     clientSoTimeout="100000" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
     sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="100000" socketSoLinger="0"
     validateConnections="true"  keepSendSocketOpen="true" keepAlive="true">
     <receiver-threading-profile
         maxThreadsActive="5" maxThreadsIdle="5" />
     <reconnect-forever />
     <!--  <service-overrides messageReceiver="TCPMuleOut" />-->
     <service-overrides messageReceiver="ve.com.comware.socket.TCPMuleOutBasic" />
     <tcp:direct-protocol payloadOnly="true" />
 </tcp:connector>
 <flow name="socketcomware0.1Flow1" doc:name="socketcomware0.1Flow1">
         <tcp:inbound-endpoint  host="107.170.3.231" port="2020"  doc:name="TCP" responseTimeout="100000" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
         <logger message="HOLA1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         <logger message="test  ----------------- #[message.payload[0]]  -------------------#[message.payload[1]]  " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 </flow>
```

the error:

```
 org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Index: 0, Size: 0
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
     at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
     at ve.com.comware.socket.TCPMuleOutBasic$MyTcpWorker.getNextMessage(TCPMuleOutBasic.java:65)
```

Comment: Sorry, but i could not understand what you are trying to do in the message receiver class. Why wouldnt your flow work without overriding the message receiver class?

Comment: I did it because I can't found another way to do it. i take this like example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017785/tcp-server-configuration-in-mule-writing-into-client-socket) this allowed me to establish a communication with the device; but I  need to keep transferring commands and parameters in the same Socket and because in my Mule project I'll be receiving queries from multiple devices.

Comment: Okay, the scenario in the example link is that the mule flow has a tcp server, but in-order to establish the client connection, the server has to initiate the request, which is why it is done via the program. Is that your case? If you are just looking to have the responses in the same socket, you could just use the tcp inbound endpoint as request-response (assuming that you are the tcp server and you are listening for client requests).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know so that I can understand your usecase -

```
   <tcp:connector name="TCP1" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="TCP">
    <tcp:direct-protocol payloadOnly="false"/>
</tcp:connector>

 <flow name="tcp-testFlow">
        <tcp:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${host}" port="${port}" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="TCP1" doc:name="TCP"/>
        <logger message="This is what your client is sending you - #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="Hello from server - #[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>
```